# SQL Server sum of two varchar columns from their alias

Tags: sql-server-2005, concatenation, alias, calculated-columns

I have a table as shown below

```
declare @Location Table([state] nvarchar(30) null,city nvarchar(30) null)

Insert Into @Location Values('California', 'San Francisco')
Insert Into @Location Values('California', null)
Insert Into @Location Values('California', 'Orange County')
Insert Into @Location Values('California', null)
```

And a select statement as shown below

```
select 
    [state], city, [state] as CurrentState, 
    case 
       when city is null then 'Sacramento' 
       else city 
    end as CurrentCity  
from 
    @Location
```

[image]

I want a fifth column titled `Address` which gives me the sum of the columns `CurrentState` and `CurrentCity` like thus:

```
Address
California, San Francisco
California, Sacramento
California, Orange County
California, Sacramento
```

Is this possible?

I've already tried `CurrentState+', '+CurrentCity`. It doesn't work

Comment: Just do `city + ', ' + state`.

Comment: @Gordon: City, State gives me the actual column values with nulls. This has to come from the alias

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you want:

```
select [state], city, [state] as CurrentState, 
       coalesce(city, 'Sacramento') as CurrentCity, 
       (coalesce(city, 'Sacramento') + ', ' + coalesce(state, '')) as Address, 
from @Location;
```

That is, you need to repeat the logic.  But `coalesce()` is much simpler than a `case` statement.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. This helps.

Answer (score 1):

This also works

```
select 
    [state], city, [state] as CurrentState, 
    case 
       when city is null then 'Sacramento' 
       else city 
    end as CurrentCity,
    case 
       when city is null then [state] + ', ' + 'Sacramento' 
       else [state] + ', ' + [city]
    end as Address

from 
    @Location
```

But for a cleaner approach, I would prefer

```
SELECT
    [STATE]
    ,[CITY]
    ,CurrentState = [STATE]
    ,CurrentCity = ISNULL ([CITY] , 'Sacramento')
    ,Address = [STATE] + ', ' + ISNULL ([CITY] , 'Sacramento')
FROM @Location
```

OR

```
SELECT
    [STATE]
    ,[CITY]
    ,CurrentState = [STATE]
    ,CurrentCity = COALESCE ([CITY] , 'Sacramento')
    ,Address = [STATE] + ', ' + COALESCE ([CITY] , 'Sacramento')
FROM @Location
```

I know that you have tagged with SQLServer 2005, however, if you are using in future Sql Server2012, you can even try with **IIF statement** as

```
SELECT
    [STATE]
    ,[CITY]
    ,CurrentState = [STATE]
    ,CurrentCity = IIF([CITY] IS NULL,'Sacramento',[CITY])
    ,Address= IIF([CITY] IS NULL,
                  [STATE] + ', ' +'Sacramento',
                   [STATE] + ', ' +[CITY])
FROM @Location
```

OR with **CHOOSE** also as shown under

```
SELECT
    [STATE]
    ,[CITY]
    ,CurrentState = [STATE]
    ,CurrentCity = CHOOSE(IIF([CITY] IS NULL,1,2),'Sacramento',[CITY])
    ,Address= CHOOSE(IIF([CITY] IS NULL,1,2),[STATE] + ', ' +'Sacramento',[STATE] + ', ' +[CITY])   
FROM @Location
```

All yields the same result

[image]

Hope this will be helpful.